# Jacob cook (name + his position)

Tags: phrase-choice

> **Jacob cook** is making an Italian meal right now.
>
> **Jacob, the cook,** is making an Italian meal right now.
>
> **The cook Jacob** is making an Italian meal right now.

Could you explain how to write correctly the mentioned phrase: "the name + his position"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second form, with appositive commas is correct.  You could invert it as "The cook, Jacob, is ..."

English doesn't tend to use job names as titles (with a few exceptions like Dr or Chef) So "Cook Jacob..." doesn't work, but "Chef Smith" is possible, if Jacob Smith is actually a chef.

The first form isn't idiomatic at all.  It would just about be possible in a written context with explicit brackets "Jacob [cook] is ..." in which "cook" is inserted by an editor.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the form "Jacob cook is ..." used in historical novels set in English country houses several centuries ago, and in fantasy novels set in pseudo-mideaval worlds. I suspect it is not an accurate indication of a form once used in English even there.  But possibly such a form was once used in small communities. Some such foprm might be a source for the many "occupational" surnames used in English, such as "Smith", "Fletcher", "Constable", "Potter", "Taylor", "Gardener". and the like. But if so, such a form is long obsolete, and should not now be used.